# ng bootstrap radio buttons showing traditional radios

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I'm currently using ng bootstrap with angular cli...the only problem im currently running into is that when i use the code for radio buttons/checkboxes...it shows the traditional radios and checkboxes

for example...

[image]

app.module.ts (main module)

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
  .....
})
```

html:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" [(ngModel)]="model">
    <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
        <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="left"> Left 
    </label>
    <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
        <input ngbButton type="radio" value="middle"> Middle
    </label>
    <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
        <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="right"> Right
    </label>
    </div>
```

component:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import { User } from '../../../auth/shared/services/auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-store',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  styleUrls: ['app-store.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: 'app-store.component.html'
})

export class AppStoreComponent implements OnInit {
  public radioGroupForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.radioGroupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'model': 1
    });
  }
}
```

any idea on how to make the buttons clickable and remove the traditional radios/boxes?

Comment: are you seeing errors in the console? You might have a problem with your values for left and right, try `value="left"` and `value="right"` (no square brackets)

Comment: yea no errors in the console...and i tried that no difference

Comment: Looks like bootrap js is not being included.

Comment: Did you install and import Bootstrap CSS (you should)? Did you import Bootstrap Javascript code (you should not)? Which versions of Angular and of ng-bootstrap are installed?